# Log structured data to Azure Storage table by Serilog store all object in RenderedMessage, I want column for each field in class

Tags: asp.net, azure-table-storage, serilog

I write below code to log/store logs with an objects to Azure Table Storage by using SeriLog, But I got the object stored in "RenderedMessage" column (in azure table) or "Data" column, While I need to store each field/property in the class to a separated column in the Table storage.
Please see below:

```
 var _simpleTransation = new SimpleTransation(99, "some title9", "type99");

 var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.AzureTableStorage(storage,LogEventLevel.Information,null, "LogStorage",false,null,null,null,false)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("SimpleTransation", "@_simpleTransation", true)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .CreateLogger()
                .ForContext<SimpleTransation>();

   logger.Information<SimpleTransation>("{@SimpleTransation}", _simpleTransation);
```

[image]

So I need to add columns to azure storage table that represent my object fields and not serialize my whole object inside RenderedMessage log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I need to add columns to azure storage table that represent my object fields and not serialize my whole object inside RenderedMessage log?

You could use `propertyColumns` attribute to add a new column when you write to azure table storage.

**Note**:You need to call `Enrich.FromLogContext()` and **the property would show up** in the Azure Table Storage.

Here is an article about [Enrichment](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment). Log events can be enriched with properties in various ways.

You need to use `LogContext.PushProperty` to add what property and value you want to add.

You could refer to the following code to have a try:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var storage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        string tableName = "table411";
        var exampleuser = new User { Id = 1, Name = "joey", Age = 23 };
        var _log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.AzureTableStorageWithProperties(storage, propertyColumns: new string[] { "UserId" });

        LogContext.PushProperty("UserId", exampleuser.Id);

        var logger = _log.CreateLogger();

        logger.Information("{@User}",exampleuser);
    }
    class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Screen shot:

[image]